# Gamma of a Lookback Option

Tags: options, volatility, greeks, exotics, gamma

From this book, http://docs.finance.free.fr/Options/Exotic_Options_Trading.pdf, 
it states that

> The gamma profile of a Max lookback option becomes intuitive when
>   viewing it as a ladder option. Indeed, as long as the stock goes up there
>   will be gamma on the lookback option and the gamma will decrease
>   quickly when the stock goes down, as the options below have already
>   knocked out and therefore have no gamma on them any more.

I just cannot see how this is intuitive nor why there will be gamma on the lookback option as long as the stock goes up. What I am missing here? I cant picture how this gamma would change with spot and time, moreover I could not be sure through this explanation above the curves would even be continuous.

Comment: Take the analytical value of a look back and plot gamma as a function of the maximum historical price, that should make you see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book of De Weert he approximates the price with a strip of knock-outs. For example the lookback call with fixed strike pays the (max(S) - K)+, is approximated by a strip of knockout calls with a rebate. So whenever the stock sets a new high, another call knocks out and you receive your rebate. In his example the rebates are 1 cent apart. So if the stock moves from $\$45$ to $\$50$, you will have collected $\$5$ in rebates.

Anyways:

- do you agree that a knock-out call while it is a live is long gamma?
- do you agree that a barrier option that is knocked out has no gamma?
- do you agree that a barrier option has more gamma when spot is closer to the strike?

Assuming you agree with the 3 bullets above. you can see that once the stock goes up and knocks out a few barrier options. and then spot drops, the strip of barriers will have less gamma.